# dynamoDB: random AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

i try to get an item from dynamoDB table using java aws sdk. the code works... sometimes. sometimes i can get the item and sometimes i get the exception. even though i always ask for the same existing item (i can see the item in the aws console in the browser). i run the code manually and it does only 1 request so it's not about exceeding provisioned capacity. any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

code:

```
table.getItem("Id", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

exception:

> nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User:
>   arn:aws:iam::7XXXXXXXXXX7:user/xxxxx is not authorized to perform:
>   dynamodb:GetItem on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:7XXXXXXXXXX7:table/history-test (Service:
>   AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;
>   Request ID: 0KJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXG)

Comment: It's weird that it works sometimes. To ask the obvious... does that IAM user account actually have permission to call GetItem on that table?

Comment: i don't post it as an answer because i don't know full details - the problem was bad permissions set by admins. i have no idea why it sometimes worked